# Flask config variable that comes from env var, loaded using load_dotenv and fetched using os.environ.get is sometimes None

Tags: python, flask

I am experiencing the strangest behaviour which I cannot get to the bottom of and it's driving me crazy.

I start my flask app locally using a `make` target. The command it runs is this:

```
export FLASK_APP=foodbank_southlondon.launch:main FBSL_ENVIRONMENT=dev FLASK_ENV=development && \
    . $(_VENV_ACTIVATE) && \
    flask run
```

Here are the contents of `launch.py`:

```
import logging
import os

import dotenv

from foodbank_southlondon import api, app, bff, config, oauth
from foodbank_southlondon.api import events, lists, requests
import foodbank_southlondon.views  # noqa: F401
import foodbank_southlondon.errors  # noqa: F401
import foodbank_southlondon.api.errors  # noqa: F401
import foodbank_southlondon.api.events.views  # noqa: F401
import foodbank_southlondon.api.lists.views  # noqa: F401
import foodbank_southlondon.api.requests.views  # noqa: F401
import foodbank_southlondon.bff.views  # noqa: F401


# ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES
_FBSL_ENVIRONMENT_ENV_VAR = "FBSL_ENVIRONMENT"


def main():
    environment = os.environ.get(_FBSL_ENVIRONMENT_ENV_VAR)
    app.logger.setLevel(logging.INFO if environment == "prod" else logging.DEBUG)
    env_file_path = os.path.join(app.root_path, "..", f"{environment}.env")
    app.logger.info(f"Loading .env file, {env_file_path}...")
    dotenv.load_dotenv(env_file_path)
    app.logger.info(f"Loading environment, {environment} ...")
    app.config.from_object(config.CONFIGURATIONS[environment])
    app.logger.info(f"Initialising APIs, OAuth, attaching namespaces and registering blueprints  ...")
    oauth.register(name="google", server_metadata_url="https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration",
                   client_kwargs={"scope": "openid email profile"})
    oauth.init_app(app)
    api.rest.init_app(api.blueprint)
    api.rest.add_namespace(events.namespace)
    api.rest.add_namespace(lists.namespace)
    api.rest.add_namespace(requests.namespace)
    app.register_blueprint(api.blueprint, url_prefix="/api")
    bff.rest.init_app(bff.blueprint)
    app.register_blueprint(bff.blueprint, url_prefix="/bff")
    return app
```

Here are the trimmed down contents of `config.py`, the important thing to note is that my dev config class inherits from the base class and the base class is the only place that defines **GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET** and it comes from os.environ.get:

```
import os


class _Config(object):
    ...
    GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET = os.environ.get("FBSL_CLIENT_SECRET")
    ...


class DevelopmentConfig(_Config):
    ... # i don't set GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET here


class ProductionConfig(_Config):
    ...

CONFIGURATIONS = {
    "dev": DevelopmentConfig,
    "prod": ProductionConfig
}
```

Inside `dev.env`:

```
FBSL_CLIENT_SECRET = secret
FBSL_SA_KEY = secret
```

**Additional Context**

My backend serves a react SPA as a set of static files. When a user hits my website, e.g. localhost:5000/ my flask route immediately redirects them to login with Google (using `authlib`). Google sends them back to my /auth callback and if they have permission to my site, I then redirect them back to / but this time I serve them static files rather than redirecting them to login. Authlib requires the app config variable, `GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET` to be set to be able to authorize them with Google.

**THE PROBLEM**

The first time I start my server, the server starts just fine, I see the log messages that show that dev.env is being executed. There's the typical double output you get when debug mode is on:

```
export FLASK_APP=foodbank_southlondon.launch:main FBSL_ENVIRONMENT=dev FLASK_ENV=development && \
. .venv/bin/activate && \
flask run
 * Serving Flask app "foodbank_southlondon.launch:main" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: development
 * Debug mode: on
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 277-037-026
[2020-05-08 09:21:50,778] INFO in launch: Loading .env file, /home/ac/Projects/Home/foodbank-southlondon/backend/foodbank_southlondon/../dev.env...
[2020-05-08 09:21:50,779] INFO in launch: Loading environment, dev ...
[2020-05-08 09:21:50,779] INFO in launch: Initialising APIs, OAuth, attaching namespaces and registering blueprints  ...
[2020-05-08 09:21:50,919] INFO in launch: Loading .env file, /home/ac/Projects/Home/foodbank-southlondon/backend/foodbank_southlondon/../dev.env...
[2020-05-08 09:21:50,919] INFO in launch: Loading environment, dev ...
[2020-05-08 09:21:50,920] INFO in launch: Initialising APIs, OAuth, attaching namespaces and registering blueprints  ...
```

I can visit localhost:5000 and I get redirected to login, I login and I see the website.

If I then stop my webserver and start it again in **EXACTLY** the same way, I see the **EXACT** same terminal output. If I then visit localhost:5000, I see this error along with its traceback in the debugger:

```
authlib.integrations.base_client.errors.OAuthError
authlib.integrations.base_client.errors.OAuthError: invalid_request: client_secret is missing.
```

If I click into the debugger and open an interactive shell and type:

```
from foodbank_southlondon import app
print(app.config)
```

I see all config variables and EVERYTHING is set as expected except the 2 config variables that I load using os.environ.get, they are both None.

In order for me to *fix* this crazy problem, I have to do something to config.py to "change" it. For example, if I write `print(GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET)` right underneath where it is defined, not only do I see this output which is not a None value but also, the very act of me introducing the print statement fixes it! But then if I stop the server and start it again, I have the same problem again and I need to change the file in some way.

**Final point:** If I don't stop the server and I let the reloader just reload, I avoid this problem.

I'm assuming that I won't encounter this problem in production but it makes development so painful and it's just an insane problem. It's as if I have some sort of weird environment variable cacheing problem between stopping and starting the server. I have no idea. Please help!

Comment: Where are you calling the `from dotenv import load_dotenv` after that you should `load_dotenv()` so your env vars will be loaded in current environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sigh, it was to do with executon order... importing config module before environment variable set and thus os.environ.get evaluating to None. Have made the class variables that use os.environ.get into instance properties (@property) and I instantiate the class in my config dict to get around this.